# `vite build` is throwing `Could not resolve "../internals/window" from "../internals/window?commonjs-external"`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I have recently migrated from CRA to Vite. Everything went smooth, yet the build script is throwing an error.
Seems to be a RollupError
`Could not resolve "../internals/window" from "../internals/window?commonjs-external"`

When I remove the define object from my config, the build succeeds yet the dev server stops working

I am using the vite 4
here is my config

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import viteTsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import svgrPlugin from "vite-plugin-svgr";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  return {
    plugins: [react(), viteTsconfigPaths(), svgrPlugin()],
    preview: {
      port: 3000,
    },
    build: {
      outDir: "build",
      rollupOptions: {
        external: ["jss-plugin-window"],
      },
    },
    define: {
      global: "window"
    },
    server: {
      open: true,
      port: 3000,
    },
    envPrefix: "REACT_APP_",
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following the bypass the issue, got the solution from here: https://dev.to/lico/issues-that-i-encountered-and-how-to-deal-with-them-while-migrating-from-cra-to-vite-51pg

```
 define: {
    ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? {global: 'window'} : {})
  }
```